# innodb_buffer_pool and redis which is best?

Tags: mysql, database, redis, innodb

both innodb_buffer_pool and redis they are all suppert memery. and they are all support LRU. so why should i use both redis and mysql at same time?, what's the point of using redis in my case.

my application is coding use golang(game server). It provides http api. but applications are becoming more complex. it has 100 sql query per request (20% insert/update, 80% select).because the game hasn't been released yet so
the data set is small, about 400000 rows, stress testing in progress,i want to improving it. i increased innodb_buffer_pool_size,the performance improved but it didn't meet my expectations. so i want using redis.

thanks for you answer

Comment: What are you using these databases for ? What specific storage and access pattern? Is there a problem you are solving? Edit question with details.

Comment: What do you mean by "100 sql query per request"?  Is that like a web page that needs 100 `SELECTs` to generate the data?  If so, let's see a sampling; maybe there is a better way to write the SQL.

Answer (score 1):

If the data is changing, the buffer_pool can give you up-to-the-second data; no external caching mechanism can.

It is usually folly to have a cache in front of another cache.

How big is the dataset?  What do the queries look like?  (That is, please provide more info so we can come closer to answering *your* question.)